# Usage of exec() method on create query

Tags: node.js, mongoose, callback

I have a situation where I want to put all the business logic and callbacks in one place and mongoose queries in one place. So I'm making use of .exec() method for that purpose and handle its callback in service module. I'm successful with find query with exec()

**repository module:**

```
const findAUser = userName => {
    return Users.findOne({username: userName});
}
```

**Service Module**

```
repository.findAUser(user.username).exec((error, document) => {
            console.log(document);
            if(error) {
                rejectGeneric(reject);
            } else {
                  ..............................
```

But i'm not able to achieve the same with create query of mongoose

```
const createAUser = user => {
    return Users.create(user);
}
```

And the below code doesn't work

```
repository.createAUser(user).exec((error, document) => {
    ....................................
}
```

How to use exec() method on mongoose create query? Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by using callback option, and my resolution looks like this:

**repository**

```
    const createAUser = (user, callback) => {
        return Users.create(user, (error, document) => callback(error, document));
    }
```

**Service**

```
    repository.createAUser(user, (error, document) => {
        if(error) {
            // Do stuff for error handling
        } else {
            // Do stuff for success scenario
        }
    });
```